# How to display another text from the edittext when the button is clicked?

Tags: android, button

I have here my button onclick listener. I just want to ask if how will I modify my onclick listener everytime the button was clicked? It's like you're going to display again the text from the edittext after displaying the another one. And when the time comes that the layout become full of textview it will automatically change the layout in scroll view layout. Here's my initial code:

```
  post = (Button)findViewById(R.id.poststat);
      post.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                String post = et.getText().toString();
                et.setText("");
                pst.setText(post);

                bg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Comment: Try with a counter. Because onclick will be called again and again and therefore you have to have a switch statement to distinguish it with some variable

Comment: Sorry but can you please provide an example code? I'm new into android, so that's why. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create two OnClickListener objects and assign each one in the click of the other.

For example:

```
View.OnClickListener listener1 = new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        //Whatever you want to do
        //TODO
        //Finally
        yourButton.setClickListener(listener2);
    }
}

View.OnClickListener listener2 = new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        //Whatever you want to do
        //TODO
        //Finally
        yourButton.setClickListener(listener1);
    }
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks. But can i personally ask you some questions?